# Erro ao instanciar dois ou mais PDO em classes diferentes

Tags: php, pdo, instanciar-objeto

Vou começar com o erro exibido:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught PDOException: You cannot serialize or
> unserialize PDO instances in [no active file] on line 0

No projeto tenho a classe *Carrinhos* e a classe *Marcas*, ambas são subclasses de uma classe chamada `Database`, na qual faço a conexão com o banco de dados e executo o CRUD, etc.

O erro aconteceu quando tentei chamar dois controller ao mesmo tempo, um para listar os registros da classe `Carrinhos` e outro para listar os registros da classe `Marcas`. Segue os métodos usados:

Para **conectar** ao banco: (é executado quando a classe *Carrinhos* e a classe *Marcas* são instanciadas)

```
private function connect($line)
{
    if(is_null($this->connection))
    {
        try {
            if ($conn = $this->tryConnect($line, $this->database))
                return $conn;
            else
                return $this->tryConnect($line);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::register($e->getMessage() . "In l:" . __LINE__);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
        return $this->connection;

}
private function tryConnect($line, $dbname = null)
{
    try
    {
        if(!is_null($dbname))
            $dbname =  ';dbname=' . $dbname;
        Session::set("teste", $dbname);
        $conn = new PDO
        (
            'mysql:host=' . Settings::get('dbhost') . $dbname,
            Settings::get('dbuser'),
            Settings::get('dbpassword'),
            array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
        );
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING);
        Log::register("Is connect \nIn l:".$line, "mysql_success");
        return $conn;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        Log::register($e->getMessage()."In l:" .__LINE__);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Para **listar** os registros de cada classe uso:

```
public function listAll($pager = null, $criteria = null)
{
    $data = $this->clear();
    $sql = "";

    if($pager instanceof Pager and $criteria instanceof Criteria)
        $sql =  "SELECT *" . " FROM {$this->addCriteria($criteria)} LIMIT {$pager->range()['min']}, {$pager->range()['max']};";
    else if($pager instanceof Pager)
        $sql =  "SELECT *" . " FROM {$data['table']} LIMIT {$pager->range()['min']}, {$pager->range()['max']};";

    else if($criteria instanceof Criteria)
        $sql = "SELECT {$criteria->getSelect()}" . " FROM {$this->addCriteria($criteria)};";
    else if(!$pager instanceof Pager)
        $sql = "SELECT *" . " FROM {$data['table']};";

    if($this->debug)
        var_dump($sql);

    if($this->connection = $this->connect(__LINE__))
    {
        try
        {
            $prepare = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
            if($criteria instanceof Criteria)
                foreach ($criteria->getValues() as $key => $value)
                    $prepare->bindValue(":$key", $value);

            $prepare->execute();
            $list = $prepare->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $return = array();

            foreach ($list as $row)
                array_push($return, $this->fills($row));

            Log::register("List All execute of: " . $sql. "\nIn l:" . __LINE__, "mysql_success");
            return $return;
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            Log::register($e->getMessage()."In l:" .__LINE__);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Onde *Pager* e *Criteria* não veem ao caso.

E por fim o método para finalizar a conexão:

```
private function close($prepare, $action, $line)
{
    if($prepare instanceof PDOStatement)
    {
        if($prepare->execute())
        {
            Log::register($action . " execute of: " . $prepare->queryString . "\nIn l:$line", "mysql_success");
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
                unset($_POST[$key]);
            $this->connection = null;
            Saved::destroy();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Pelo que vejo o erro seria que está tentando usar duas conexões simultâneas no mesmo banco de dados, a solução que pesquisei parece que seria usar o [__sleep() ou __wakeup()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.magic.php), mas pesquisando não consegui entender muito bem, alguém poderia me ajudar na resolução do erro?

Comment: O erro diz que uma PDOException foi lançada porém não teve nenhum `try` para capturar ela. O código que gera o erro pode não estar na pergunta. Uma sugestão para tentar isolar o erro é primeiro verifique se isso acontece com instancia do PDO ou várias. Se possível instale um debuger como Xdebug e configure uma IDE (eclipse/phpStorm) e roda o seu código com break point depois é só ir passo a passo até o erro estourar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro não era na instanciação do `PDO` como eu achei (pois nas pesquisas todos resultados falavam esse mesmo problema), e sim porque estava armazenando um `array` de objetos em uma variável de sessão, mesmo fazendo `serialize` não estava dando resultado.

A solução foi passar os objetos para `array`, então aproveitei um método que tinha no meu `Database` que transforma meu *model* em `array`:

```
private function clear()
{
    $attr = get_class_vars(get_class($this->object));
    $attr2 = get_class_vars('Database');

    foreach ($attr as $key => $value)
        if($key != 'table' and key_exists($key, $attr2))
            unset($attr[$key]);

    $data = array();
    foreach ($attr as $key => $value)
        $data[$key] = $this->object->$key;
    return $data;
}
```

Então fiz um método público para pegar já o objeto como array:

```
public function vars()
{
    return $this->clear();
}
```

No `controller`, criei um método que pega a lista de objetos e transforma em uma lista de *arrays*:

```
public function toArray($object)
{
    if(is_array($object))
    {

        $variables = array();
        foreach ($object as $o)
        {
            array_push($variables, $this->scan($o));
        }
        return $variables;
    }
    else if(is_object($object))
    {
        return $this->scan($object);
    }
}

private function scan($o)
{
    if(is_object($o))
    {
        $vars = $o->vars();
        foreach ($vars as $k => $v)
        {
            if(is_object($v))
            {
                $vars[$k] = $this->toArray($v);
            }
        }
        return $vars;
    }
}
```

Para outros o código pode parecer estranho, mas se adapta a estrutura do framework: https://github.com/LeonardoVilarinho/framework

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi do seu código você está tentando fazer uma classe de conexão usando o padrão **[Singleton](http://www.devmedia.com.br/php-singleton-aplicando-o-padrao-de-projeto-na-pratica/28469)**. Acho que o caminho é este. Uma classe de conexão no padrão singleton ficaria assim:

```
<?php
class SingletonDB
{
    public $db;
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct()
    {
        $this -> dbhc= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example', "root", "");
    }

    //singleton pattern
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance))
        {
            $object = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $object;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}

?>
```

Pegando uma instância da classe

```
$db = database::getInstance();
```

Fonte: https://acomputerengineer.wordpress.com/2013/06/16/pdo-connection-class-in-php-oop-approach-with-singleton-pattern/